# Spring-ReactiveWeb! Netty doesnt start after add Swagger 2 documentation

Tags: spring, swagger-ui

Does Swagger support Spring Reactive-Web?

I am trying to write a simple crud application with Reactive Web and Reactive Mongo. Everything works fine. But when I add Swagger to my project, Netty doesn't start.

Here is my controller class:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import uz.n0d1r.datas.Point;
import uz.n0d1r.repository.PointRepository;

@RestController(value = "/points")
public class PointController {

    private final PointRepository pointRepository;

    public PointController(PointRepository pointRepository) {
        this.pointRepository = pointRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping
    Mono<Void> create(@RequestBody Point point) {
        return pointRepository.save(point).then();
    }

    @GetMapping
    Flux<Point> list() {
        return this.pointRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Swagger Config:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ParameterBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.service.Parameter;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class TrackServiceSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        ParameterBuilder aParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
//        aParameterBuilder.name("Authorization").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(true).build();
        List<Parameter> header = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
        header.add(aParameterBuilder.build());
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(paths())
                .build()
                .globalOperationParameters(header);
    }

    // Describe your apis
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Track-Service APIs")
                .description("description goes here ")
                .contact(new Contact("Nodirbek Sadullayev", "n0d1r.uz", "n.sadullayev@gmail.com"))
                .version("1.0-SNAPSHOT")
                .build();
    }

    // Only select apis that matches the given Predicates.
    private Predicate<String> paths() {
        // Match all paths except /error
        return Predicates.and(
                PathSelectors.regex("/.*"),
                Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*"))
        );
    }
}
```

My dependencies list below:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Error log:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveWebServerConfiguration$ReactorNettyAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
            at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:59) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:44) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at uz.n0d1r.TrackServiceApplication.main(TrackServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveWebServerConfiguration$ReactorNettyAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:117) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:82) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:56) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M6.jar:2.0.0.M6]
            ... 13 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
            at springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ObjectMapperConfigurer.java:45) ~[springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1696) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
            ... 30 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestions ? thanks!

Comment: It's clearly telling you that it's missing a required class: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter. Did you try adding the spring-webmvc dependency?

Comment: yeah, I already add spring-webmvc. app run successfully, but another problem accour

Comment: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html cant load page. this url retrive Error: There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).

Comment: You get that error when you try to navigate to a page but you've not got a route set up to handle GET requests to that URL. You've got something not set up right with swagger. My guess is that your swagger-ui.html is actually relative to some other path. Spring-boot should report its routes at startup to log/console. That's also a completely different question than this one.

Comment: This (spring boot 2.x and spring 5 features )isn’t supported yet in springfox as of 2.7.0. It is in the works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swagger 3 will be soon released, and it includes support for netty.

By that time, you can use the snapshot version:

```
{
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-spring-webflux:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

}

and you enable it with `@EnableSwagger2WebFlux`

source: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1773

Comment: this is not working for me I am using same config with spring boot 2.1.7 on windows platform, can you assist ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunetely swagger does not support spring webflux yet. Only solution here
https://github.com/armdev/springboot2-swagger , but again you cant use full webflux API, you should go with unblocking tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

in this https://github.com/armdev/webfluxswagger app , you have used Docket class which gives compile error. I think it needs dependency of springfox-spring-web whhich is not in pom.xml.
Let me know if its not correct.